# Generate percentage prediction label by using BERT multi-label classification

Tags: python, multilabel-classification, bert-language-model

I'm currently working on multi-label classification task for text data. I have a dataframe with an ID column, text column and several columns which are text label containing only 1 or 0.

I used an existing solution proposed on this website [Kaggle Toxic Comment Classification using Bert](https://www.kaggle.com/javaidnabi/toxic-comment-classification-using-bert/output) which permits to express in percentage its degree of belonging to each label.

Now, that I've trained my model I would like to use my model with new unlabeled text in order to obtain percentage of belonging to each label :

I've found this solution on this [website](https://pysnacks.com/machine-learning/bert-text-classification-with-fine-tuning/#multi-class-text-classification-using-bert) and more especially this part code that I want to add at the end of my Kaggle code :

```
texts = [
  '.........',
  '.........',
  '..........',
  '..........',
]

for text in texts:
  ids, segments = tokenizer.encode(text, max_len=SEQ_LEN)
  inpu = np.array(ids).reshape([1, SEQ_LEN])
  predicted = (model.predict([inpu,np.zeros_like(inpu)]) >= 0.5).astype(int)
  labels = [
    label
    for i, label in enumerate(labels_ordered)
    if predicted[0][i]
  ]
  print ("%s: %s" % (text, labels))
```

But this solution only permit me to obtain class prediction but not the percentage percentage prediction for each class.

Do you have any idea how can I do to adapt this last pat of code to my Kaggle code and get percentage prediction ?

Comment: I strongly think that if you don't have a binary classifier for each class you can't have percentage for each of them.. to be confirmed